# D3 Force Directed Graph breaks on zoom

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming

I'm using version 7.3.0 of d3 and I have based my code on [this example](https://observablehq.com/@d3/force-directed-graph). My problem is that when I'm zooming in (or out) the layout of the circles breaks and becomes

[image]

while initially was like this

[image]

The code that implements the zoom is

```
    const zoomed = d3.zoom()
      .scaleExtent([0, 3])
      .on('zoom', event => {
        graph.selectAll('g').attr('transform', event.transform);
      });
```

I have noticed that if I add the following line of code, then it prevents it from breaking.

```
    const zoomed = d3.zoom()
      .scaleExtent([0, 3])
      .on('zoom', event => {
        graph.selectAll('g').attr('transform', event.transform);

        // This line prevents zoom from breaking
        simulation.restart();
      });
```

But the downside is that it becomes noticeably slower. Is there a more efficient way to prevent it from breaking like that?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Same problem (but only occurs using zoom after sim stops), the simulation.restart() allowed me to move forward, thanks! I tried simulation.ticks(# in here) but it does not work. I am using v4.